How to forward mirrored packet data to an external instance's VNIC using tc and AWS Traffic Mirroring?
I'm testing mirroring incoming Ethernet packets within Linux, forwarding them to another Ethernet interface, and then sending them to another external VNIC.(ens3->ens5) I successfully mirrored internal Ethernet using 'tc', but I'm facing issues forwarding to an external VNIC using AWS traffic mirroring. It seems like the packet data fails to reach the external destination. Could this be due to losing the packet route? Is there a way to forward external packets like this?
